# Add a thick line to bottom of entire row based on value of cel in column AZ

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range Range("A3:AZ" & lastrow) where the last column is either true or false and I want to add a thick bottom border to the entire row if the value of Az is true.

I can add a THIN bottom row using standard conditional formatting but for some reason no other weight borders are available. (I'm on a Mac by the way)

I think I need a VBA macro to do this but haven't been successful with that either

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Option Compare Text

Sub Add_Thick_Line()
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "AZ").End(xlUp).Row

If Range("AZ" & lastrow).Value = "true" Then Range("A" & lastrow, "AZ" & lastrow).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick

End Sub
```